# How to get RotationMatrix from yaw, pitch and roll

Tags: java, android, matrix, opengl-es, android-sensors

Hi I managed to find yaw, pitch and roll from acceleratoin and magnetic sensor in my Android app. I now want to rotate my Camera Target(min3d) around a point in my scene according to does angles. The result is to be able to look in a 3d scene by moving the android device around. I've been trying for days almost read all related answers in SO but I just can't have it work.

The movement I get has absolutely no sens. I verified that my yaw is between 0-360 and is correct, pitch is between -90 and 90 and is correct and finally the roll is between -180 and 180 and is consistent.

Basically I am doing matrix rotation and multiplication by my target and up vector.

```
float[] rotation = new float[16];   
Matrix.setIdentityM(rotation, 0);
Matrix.rotateM(rotation, 0, (float) Math.toDegrees(roll), 0, 0, 1);         
Matrix.rotateM(rotation, 0, (float) Math.toDegrees(pitch)+90f, 1, 0, 0);        
Matrix.rotateM(rotation, 0, (float) Math.toDegrees(-azimut), 0, 1, 0);      

float[] target = new float[4];
float[] source = new float[]{0,0,150,0};    
Matrix.multiplyMV(target, 0,rotation, 0, source, 0);
float targetX = target[0] + 0;
float targetY = target[1] + 150;
float targetZ = -target[2] + 0;

target = new float[4];
source = new float[]{0,1,0,0};
Matrix.multiplyMV(target, 0,rotation, 0, source, 0);
float upX = target[0];
float upY = target[1];
float upZ = target[2];

scene.camera().target.x = targetX;              
scene.camera().target.y = targetY;
scene.camera().target.z = targetZ;      
scene.camera().upAxis.x = upX;
scene.camera().upAxis.y = upY;
scene.camera().upAxis.z = upZ;
```

Initially my target is at (0,0,150) and my up vector is (0,1,0).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Found it :) Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After the roll matrix, the target vector must be consistent because the target only aim axis.

Actually, your target is not vec3(0,150,150) the target is vec3(0,0,150) indeed. You rotate it and then add vec3(0,150,0). So think about it, vec3(0,0,150) is always vec3(0,0,150) if you rotate z-axis.

## Update

Yes, rotateM() multiplies the matrix you set before and a matrix you set now, so logically there is no problem there.

```
 public static void rotateM(float[] rm, int rmOffset,
        float[] m, int mOffset,
        float a, float x, float y, float z) {
    synchronized(sTemp) {
        setRotateM(sTemp, 0, a, x, y, z);
        multiplyMM(rm, rmOffset, m, mOffset, sTemp, 0);
    }

public static void setRotateM(float[] rm, int rmOffset,
        float a, float x, float y, float z) {
    rm[rmOffset + 3] = 0;
    rm[rmOffset + 7] = 0;
    rm[rmOffset + 11]= 0;
    rm[rmOffset + 12]= 0;
    rm[rmOffset + 13]= 0;
    rm[rmOffset + 14]= 0;
    rm[rmOffset + 15]= 1;
    a *= (float) (Math.PI / 180.0f);
    float s = (float) Math.sin(a);
    float c = (float) Math.cos(a);
    if (1.0f == x && 0.0f == y && 0.0f == z) {
        rm[rmOffset + 5] = c;   rm[rmOffset + 10]= c;
        rm[rmOffset + 6] = s;   rm[rmOffset + 9] = -s;
        rm[rmOffset + 1] = 0;   rm[rmOffset + 2] = 0;
        rm[rmOffset + 4] = 0;   rm[rmOffset + 8] = 0;
        rm[rmOffset + 0] = 1;
    } else if (0.0f == x && 1.0f == y && 0.0f == z) {
        rm[rmOffset + 0] = c;   rm[rmOffset + 10]= c;
        rm[rmOffset + 8] = s;   rm[rmOffset + 2] = -s;
        rm[rmOffset + 1] = 0;   rm[rmOffset + 4] = 0;
        rm[rmOffset + 6] = 0;   rm[rmOffset + 9] = 0;
        rm[rmOffset + 5] = 1;
    } else if (0.0f == x && 0.0f == y && 1.0f == z) {
        rm[rmOffset + 0] = c;   rm[rmOffset + 5] = c;
        rm[rmOffset + 1] = s;   rm[rmOffset + 4] = -s;
        rm[rmOffset + 2] = 0;   rm[rmOffset + 6] = 0;
        rm[rmOffset + 8] = 0;   rm[rmOffset + 9] = 0;
        rm[rmOffset + 10]= 1;
    } else {
        float len = length(x, y, z);
        if (1.0f != len) {
            float recipLen = 1.0f / len;
            x *= recipLen;
            y *= recipLen;
            z *= recipLen;
        }
        float nc = 1.0f - c;
        float xy = x * y;
        float yz = y * z;
        float zx = z * x;
        float xs = x * s;
        float ys = y * s;
        float zs = z * s;
        rm[rmOffset +  0] = x*x*nc +  c;
        rm[rmOffset +  4] =  xy*nc - zs;
        rm[rmOffset +  8] =  zx*nc + ys;
        rm[rmOffset +  1] =  xy*nc + zs;
        rm[rmOffset +  5] = y*y*nc +  c;
        rm[rmOffset +  9] =  yz*nc - xs;
        rm[rmOffset +  2] =  zx*nc - ys;
        rm[rmOffset +  6] =  yz*nc + xs;
        rm[rmOffset + 10] = z*z*nc +  c;
    }
}
```

This android function rotateM() is a combined version of these three matrices below

```
void Matrix_Rotation_X(Matrix   &out_M,const float angle)
{
    float COS = (float)cos(angle);
    float SIN = (float)sin(angle);
    out_M.s[_0x0_]=  1.f;       out_M.s[_0x1_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_0x2_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_0x3_]= 0.f;
    out_M.s[_1x0_]=  0.f;       out_M.s[_1x1_]= COS;    out_M.s[_1x2_]= SIN;    out_M.s[_1x3_]= 0.f;
    out_M.s[_2x0_]=  0.f;       out_M.s[_2x1_]=-SIN;    out_M.s[_2x2_]= COS;    out_M.s[_2x3_]= 0.f;
    out_M.s[_3x0_]=  0.f;       out_M.s[_3x1_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_3x2_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_3x3_]= 1.f;
    
}

void Matrix_Rotation_Y(Matrix   &out_M, const float angle)
{
    float COS = (float)cos(angle);
    float SIN = (float)sin(angle);
    out_M.s[_0x0_]=  COS;       out_M.s[_0x1_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_0x2_]=-SIN;    out_M.s[_0x3_]= 0.f;
    out_M.s[_1x0_]=  0.f;       out_M.s[_1x1_]= 1.f;    out_M.s[_1x2_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_1x3_]= 0.f;
    out_M.s[_2x0_]=  SIN;       out_M.s[_2x1_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_2x2_]= COS;    out_M.s[_2x3_]= 0.f;
    out_M.s[_3x0_]=  0.f;       out_M.s[_3x1_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_3x2_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_3x3_]= 1.f;
}

void Matrix_Rotation_Z( Matrix  &out_M, const float angle)
{
    float COS = (float)cos(angle);
    float SIN = (float)sin(angle);
    out_M.s[_0x0_]=  COS;       out_M.s[_0x1_]= SIN;    out_M.s[_0x2_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_0x3_]= 0.f;
    out_M.s[_1x0_]=  -SIN;      out_M.s[_1x1_]= COS;    out_M.s[_1x2_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_1x3_]= 0.f;
    out_M.s[_2x0_]=  0.f;       out_M.s[_2x1_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_2x2_]= 1.f;    out_M.s[_2x3_]= 0.f;
    out_M.s[_3x0_]=  0.f;       out_M.s[_3x1_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_3x2_]= 0.f;    out_M.s[_3x3_]= 1.f;
}
```

https://github.com/sunglab/StarEngine/blob/master/math/Matrix.cpp

Comment: This would be true if I was loading the Identity matrix after each rotation which I do not.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi Ok you multiply the matrix in the func, rotateM() which I couldn't know. two things are weird to me. 1. you never normalize the up and target vectos. 2. I don't see you set the camera position. 3. just keep the up vector without the multiplication( It may be no need but I can't know if what you do in camera())

Comment: Position does not change. And why would I need to normalize these vectors?

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi Those vectors must be normalized before being a viewmatrix. If you normalize those vectors in the camera(), it is ok. How would I know if you just show calling them. You are showing simple things, and important things are calculated in each function like rotateM() and camera() if I don't see them, only I can do is to guess what might be wrong behind them

Comment: camera() contains three vectors, position, target and upVector. rotateM is from the Android OpenGL Matrix class. I don't have its implementation.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi Take a look at this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#setRotateM(float[], int, float, float, float, float) As I told you first, Matrix.rotateM() reset the matrix. It doesn't multiply any matrix in it. you now only set last one  Matrix.rotateM(rotation, 0, (float) Math.toDegrees(-azimut), 0, 1, 0);

Comment: it says "Rotates matrix m in place by angle a (in degrees) around the axis (x, y, z)." It does not specify that the matrix is reset before been rotated.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi you call rotateM() 3times. Matrix.rotateM(rotation, 0, (float) Math.toDegrees(roll), 0, 0, 1);         
Matrix.rotateM(rotation, 0, (float) Math.toDegrees(pitch)+90f, 1, 0, 0);        
Matrix.rotateM(rotation, 0, (float) Math.toDegrees(-azimut), 0, 1, 0); Then it only set the last one so I said "reset"

Comment: Why? You are not explaining why and it is not what is happening anyways. It does three rotations but it is not the end result is not conistent with what I should have. The way I see it and the way it is described in the doc is when I call rotateM on the Identity matrix, the rotation matrix contains rotation around z of roll degrees and I then rotate this matrix around x ... I do not reset the matrix back to identity and the rotation according to the doc should stack up.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not happening"? You reset roll and pitch matrices indeed. I updated it with the original code of rotateM()

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Something is off. When implement your answer nothing happens if i do not set to rotation to identity before doing anything. So this tells me something is odd with that rotateM method.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi Oh my bad... rotateM() is not equivalent to setrotateM() I should've double checked it. I updated it

Comment: Back to step one I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong while setting target and upAxis values. you are assigning angle values to target and update upAxis with same target values. However target is a x,y,z points in a 3d environment and upAxis tells the camera to take this up vector as a reference (changing upAxis rolls a camera). Here is my implementation via accels and mags motivated from [ExampleAccelerometer.java](https://github.com/mengdd/min3d/blob/master/sampleProjects/min3dSampleProject1/src/min3d/sampleProject1/ExampleAccelerometer.java)

```
public class ExampleAccelerometer extends RendererActivity implements SensorEventListener {

private SkyBox mSkyBox;
private final float[] mAccelerometerReading = new float[3];
private final float[] mMagnetometerReading = new float[3];

private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mOrientation = new float[3];
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccel, mMag;
public Number3d upAxis;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccel = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(
            Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mMag = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(
            Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);

}

public void initScene()
{
    scene.lights().add(new Light());

    mSkyBox = new SkyBox(5.0f, 2);
    mSkyBox.addTexture(SkyBox.Face.North,   R.drawable.wood_back,   "north");
    mSkyBox.addTexture(SkyBox.Face.East,    R.drawable.wood_right,  "east");
    mSkyBox.addTexture(SkyBox.Face.South,   R.drawable.wood_back,   "south");
    mSkyBox.addTexture(SkyBox.Face.West,    R.drawable.wood_left,   "west");
    mSkyBox.addTexture(SkyBox.Face.Up,      R.drawable.ceiling,     "up");
    mSkyBox.addTexture(SkyBox.Face.Down,    R.drawable.floor,       "down");
    mSkyBox.scale().y = 0.8f;
    mSkyBox.scale().z = 2.0f;
    scene.addChild(mSkyBox);

    //Initial upAxis vector
    upAxis = new Number3d(-1,0,0);
    scene.camera().upAxis = upAxis;

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mMag,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Don't receive any more updates from either sensor.
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mAccelerometerReading,
                0, mAccelerometerReading.length);
    }
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mMagnetometerReading,
                0, mMagnetometerReading.length);
    }

    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null,
            mAccelerometerReading, mMagnetometerReading);

    SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mOrientation);

    //Camera Position
    scene.camera().position.x = 0;
    scene.camera().position.y = 0;
    scene.camera().position.z = 0;

    //Camera target position (where camera looks at i.e. position of interest)
    scene.camera().target.x = 0;
        scene.camera().target.y = 0;
        scene.camera().target.z = 50;

        //To multiply target with rotation create a temp vector with 4 parameter
        float[] p = new float[4];
        p[0] = scene.camera().target.x;
        p[1] = scene.camera().target.y;
        p[2] = scene.camera().target.z;
        p[3] = 1;

        //Rotate target according to the rotation matrix derived via accel and mag sensor
        float[] target = new float[4];
        Matrix.multiplyMV(target, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, p, 0);

//      set rotated camera target (this creates 2d rotation with roll and pitch)
        scene.camera().target.x = target[0];
        scene.camera().target.y = target[1];
        scene.camera().target.z = target[2];

//      change up axis for rolling with yaw parameter
        upAxis.x = (float)(Math.cos(mOrientation[0]));
        upAxis.y = (float) (Math.sin(mOrientation[0]));
        upAxis.z = 0;
        scene.camera().upAxis = upAxis;

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working because when we have a roll and/or a pitch, The camera up vector should change too.